# Coloring objects in ray tracing

Tags: c++, raytracing

I'm trying to render a screen. So far, I have intersected my rays with the objects in the scene and if there is an intersection, I set a random color to that intersection.

What I need to do next is color pixels according to their values. I have watched more than 10 tutorials, read several websites about coloring the pixels. However, the file I'm reading does not have colors of the objects. Instead it has the following:

- An ambient light, with rgb color
- A point light, with rgb color and position
- Objects have ambient, diffuse, specular, mirror reflectance(in rgb) and a phong exponent(a value).

Also, I know that the intensity of the light emitted is proportional to the square of the distance(as distance becomes larger, there is less light on an  object).

If I had the color of the object, I could use the algorithm below:

```
Color3 trace(..)
{
    ...
    Color3 ambient = object.color * 0.3;
    Color3 phong = phongModel(..) or object.color;
    Color3 reflection = trace(..);

    return ambient + phong + reflection;
}
```

as in stated in: [How to compute reflected color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865353/how-to-compute-reflected-color)

I don't have the color of the object, just reflectance values. How can I calculate the color of the object?

Comment: Why not just assume a default color for objects (e.g.: white)?

Comment: Well, good assumption. It might be this, I'm going to try this. I feel like an idiot for not thinking this

Comment: It is better to try a gray rather full than white, so you can see "reflections"

Answer (score 1):

> However, the file I'm reading does not have colors of the objects.
>   Instead it has the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Objects have ambient, diffuse, specular, mirror reflectance(in rgb)    and a phong exponent(a value).

If you have RGB far all these, that *is* the color of the object.

Multiply incoming light with how the object reflects it in given angles and the result is the color by which it is perceived.